# Import/Export-Module: how can I import images to a custom attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, importexport, product-images

In the backend I created my own product attribute, named custom_image.

I know how to create a csv file in order to import products to magento. But it doesn't seem to work with custom image attributes.

I assumed to simply create another column, naming it custom_image, and filling it with the image, as I would do with the other default image attributes.

But it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

There is a class variable in Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product:

```
/**
 * Column names that holds images files names
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_imagesArrayKeys = array(
    '_media_image', 'image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'
);
```

You have to add your attribute name there. 
But please: don't do it in the core file, but use a rewriteor some other method for that.

Side notice: my array import wrapper AvS_FastSimpleImport supports additional image attributes, see http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/options.html. You can have a look there how it's done there.